Reason of difference output, different compiler for below code in C/C++:
We had tried to find output of the code in following. Please, give the reason for different output.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

union data1 {
    int i;
    float f;
    char ch[4];
};

int main() {
    union data1 d;
    int size;
    size=sizeof(d);
    printf("\nSize of union data is %u bytes",size);
    return 0;
}

If Code is executed in GDB
Output : 4 bytes while ch has size of 4
Output : 8 bytes while ch has size of 5
Output : 12 bytes while ch has size of 9 bytes
If code is executed in Turbo C++ compiler
Output : 4 bytes while ch has size of 4
Output : 5 bytes while ch has size of 5
Output : 9 bytes while ch has size of 9 bytes

Why ask about "C++" when your code is clearly "C"? C++ is a different language, and *(untagged) unions like this should not be used, but you should use std::variant. So when asking a question be really clear which language your question is about.

Also forget about "Turbo C" it is ancient and should no longer be used (not even by your teachers).  They could also use : https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and get modern compiler support.

First please note that Turbo C is an ancient compiler, made for DOS (which is an old 16-bit system). It is outdated, unmaintained and not used anywhere serious. Secondly, compilers are free to add padding to make sure that structures and unions are aligned properly for the target system, as an optimization.

Different compilers might pack structs/unions differently. What exacly do you think is wrong here ?

Also see Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?

Different compilers compile differently

Padding is added probably.

Enable compiler warnings.The return of sizeof isn't type int (though that isn't the reason for it reporting different sizes) If you are on windows, VS2022 Community Edition is free and is an excellent compiler. If you want a Linux like environment on window, then either use WSL and install gcc or install MSYS2. Both also excellent.

@DavidC.Rankin does your "excellent compiler" regarding VS2022 refer to C or C++? I didn't check lately but IMHO VS compilers weren't really good C compilers in the past.

@Gerhardh we are speaking in terms relative to TurboC++. I'm a Linux guy, but I'm not going to knock cl.exe for somebody who is now using TurboC/C++. Is cl my compiler? No, but it more than mows the grass for just about any project anybody asking questions here needs. There may be the 1% with specific requirements that it is "less than optimal" for, but other than that, it works. I've not had cl fail to compile anything using /Tc or /TC, but I certainly prefer gcc or clang compared to the 8G install of VS.

"Turbo C++" can mean anything out of several generations of Borland compilers, including one C++03 compiler released in the mid 2000s. From what I remember, that one would have way better C conformance in C mode than MSVC in C mode... which admittedly doesn't say much. Anyway the important part is to not use a C++ compiler at all, because union type-punning isn't well-defined in C++ and so the compiler could do anything, including skipping out on padding or generating code leading to misaligned access.

Short answer: One compiler adds padding. The other doesn't.
